# How to get the last tuple from a table with SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to get a field from the last tuple I have inserted to a table using SQL Server 2008 R2?

Comment: Could you provide a little more detail? It is hard to tell what you are asking.

Comment: "latest" in what sense?? By date?? By ID?? By what........

Comment: Do you have an identity column or some other way to identify the last row inserted? Unless you have something to `ORDER BY`, there's no way to know what order rows will be returned in.

Comment: How do you know separate processes haven't inserted data into that table so that it is undecidable which came last?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, what you need to do is:

```
SELECT TOP 1 (list of fields)
FROM dbo.YourTable
ORDER BY (some column) DESC
```

You need to define **how to order** the data so that you get the "latest" . If you sort by string, int or datetime, you'll probably want to sort in a descending order to get the most recent first.

Since you didn't provide any table structure or field names at all, this is the best we can do..... next time: please ask a bit more focused - provide more details! We're good programmer - but not mind readers. We don't know your system or your database or your setup - you need to tell us.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way without an identity or "inserteddateTime" column to find this out. A table is an unordered collection of data and only an ORDER BY will impart an definitive ordering. You can not rely on anything else.

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY Whatever DESC
```

Can you explain more about the bigger picture please?